# cannot install panther under symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-panther, facebook-webdriver

I really need help because I cannot install panther at Symfony 5 project. The Symfony/panther requires facebook/webdriver and everytime I did : composer require facebook/webdriver or composer req symfony/panther

I got this error message :

```
- facebook/webdriver 1.7.1 requires symfony/process ^2.8 || ^3.1 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- facebook/webdriver 1.7.0 requires symfony/process ^2.8 || ^3.1 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for facebook/webdriver ^1.7 -> satisfiable by facebook/webdriver[1.7.0, 1.7.1].
```

I use Composer version 1.9.1 and PHP 7.2.14

Thanks a lot

Comment: As per your error logs seems to me `facebook/webdriver` does not support `symfony/process: ^5.0` yet so you will have to wait or downgrade your project to SF 4

Comment: The issue seems to be tracked here https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/706

Answer (score 0):

It's because symfony/process package has no version with suitable stability for your application. I just had the same problem and adding "minimum-stability": "dev" to composer.json solved this issue for me.

Minimum-stability is "stable" by default.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be fixed in next release of `facebook/webdriver`. For now you can install dev version of this package:
`composer require facebook/webdriver:^1.8@dev`
And after that you can install `symfony/panther` 
Issue here: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/issues/712